# What is the difference between Docker@0, Docker@1 and Docker@2 in azure devops pipeline task?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I Could find any microsoft documentation explaining the difference between Docker@0, Docker@1 etc.
There are some difference between these I could see, for example the azureSubscription property is only available in Docker@0, while tags usually found only in Docker@2.

So far the only link available is [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/docker?view=azure-devops)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such doc explaining the difference between the 3 versions, `Docker@2` is currently default version for yaml, it's recommended to use this version for your pipeline.

But if you'd like to, you can check below items for the difference:

1. You can use `classic editor` to check the task notes:
   [image]
2. In addition, you can find the 3 tasks on [github link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks).

[image]

You can check commit history to check the change roadmap.

Answer (score 2):

You probably will not find details about differences between them, however the last one is recomended to use. But if you want to check source code - it is available here:

- [Docker@0](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DockerV0)
- [Docker@1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DockerV1)
- [Docker@2](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/DockerV2)

There is no even readme for specific version of the task.